# Errors using yuicompressor

Tags: javascript, java, c#, yui-compressor

I am getting some errors when trying to run yuicompressor.

it says:

```
[error] 1:2:illegal character
[error] 1:2:syntax error
[error] 1:3 illegal character
```

Could this be because I am saving it as the wrong encoding or something?

Comment: Could you at least post the offending line? The first line, assuming it doesn't count from zero?

Comment: Any luck here Homestead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have seen issues with YUICompressor and files that are saved in UTF-8 with the Byte Order Mark (BOM).  The default for Visual Studio 2008 seems to be to save them this way.  To solve it, I had to save the file with a different encoding.  In VS2008, this was **File - Advanced Save Options - Encoding : Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)**.

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to use this encoding when outputting a file via Powershell? I'm concatenating my files with Powershell, and like most apps it likes to use the BOM.

Answer (score 8):

I ran across this issue today.  Another fix is to provide the `--charset utf-8` option on the command line.

Comment: Setting the charset option did not help me with this issue. Only Kevin's answer (the accepted one) seems to work for me.

Comment: +1 - This worked great for me. (VS 2010, Windows 7, compressor version 2.4.2)

Comment: This worked for me too (VS2005, Windows XP, compressor version 2.4.2)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to saving under "UTF-8 without signature encoding", I had to switch to Windows style line endings (CR LF).

Answer (score 0):

While viewing the .js file in Visual Studio 2008... File -> Advanced Save Options -> Unicode (UTF-8 without signature).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is using Powershell to concatenate files, I used the following Powershell script to circumvent this problem:

```
Get-Content `
JavaScript/file01.js,`
JavaScript/file02.js,`
JavaScript/file03.js `
 | Set-Content JavaScript/Concat.js -Encoding Ascii

java.exe -jar ../../yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar JavaScript/Concat.js -o JavaScript/Concat.min.js preserve-semi --charset ascii --type js
```

Notice the ascii encoding parameters on both the concatenation and YUICompressor call.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with encodings using the .NET version of the YuiCompressor.

Fixed adding the `EncodingType="UTF8"` in my configuration file:

```
<CssCompressorTask        EncodingType="UTF8" SourceFiles="@(CssFiles)"        OutputFile="path\styles.min.css" />
<JavaScriptCompressorTask EncodingType="UTF8" SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)" OutputFile="path\scripts.min.js" />
```

For more encoding options, see the [docs](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/documentation).